# Can I divide a scene into two layers of equal sizes?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I need to divide a scene in to two layers. So that I can write same methods for two layers.
 So I may get two functionalities. But can I make that ? Is there a possibility in cocos2d? 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just create two different layer classes and add instances of each to your scene.

```
CCScene *scene = [MyScene node];
[scene addChild:[MyFirstLayer node]];
[scene addChild:[MySecondLayer node]];
```

Comment: After adding the two layers should we use z tags to determine which is on top of the other ? Or can I divide the two layers by coordinates(some part of screen to MyFirstLayer and remaining part to MySecond Layer).
Thank You.